# Google Speech API working example for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

The Node JS example in the Google Speech API documentation is for v1 and doesn't work. It simply returns an empty response even when I use 1 channel 16000Hz FLAC.

I also tried this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-speech but I cannot get authentication to work, even though I'm using the right key.

If anyone knows of a working Node example for the v2 API, I'd be grateful, I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 3):

There were some quirks with the v1 APIs and it took them a little bit longer for them to publish the node gRPC lib than some of the other languages.

You can find the v2 docs here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/speech/0.2.0/speech

You might also consider using [Sonus](https://github.com/evancohen/sonus) which also supports hotword detection (aka keyword spotting). Disclaimer: this is my project

Comment: Can I use Sonus for speech to text transcription of long audio/video files?